# Does a host/domain used solely for MX records pointing elsewhere need an A record?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I've got a domain on dns.he.net that only has an SOA record, NS records, and one MX (pointing to a totally different host). Does my domain need an A record? Currently nslookup fails since there is no IP associated with it. But mail seems to get to the MX host just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not need an A record. And if there is no IP address associated with it, it shouldn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add... for the purposes of SMTP, you strictly don't need an A record at the apex *unless you do not have an MX record*.  Most mail transport agents (MTAs) will, by default, look for an MX record first and if one is not found look for an A record and attempt to deliver to wherever that A record points.  I'm not advocating you do this, so by all means use an MX record for mail, but just know that this fallback behavior exists.

Comment: every _compliant_ mail server should do that.

Answer (score 0):

`nslookup` is failing because by default it asks for an A record.

```
~/bin/vmware@precious% nslookup -query=mx umich.edu
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
umich.edu   mail exchanger = 0 mx2.umich.edu.
umich.edu   mail exchanger = 0 mx3.umich.edu.
[ ... ]
```

try using `dig` instead, its default response is more verbose.